# BigQuery Left Join Support

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to have a left join in bigquery.

```
SELECT id,mtr,name FROM (SELECT userid,mtr,name FROM    

results_20180612_230337
LEFT JOIN table1 ON id=myid where 
partitiondate=CAST("2018-05-29" AS DATE)) LEFT JOIN `table2`  t2 
ON
(CASE
WHEN(SUBSTR(name,1,6)='000000') THEN mtr = CAST(bccbnc AS STRING)
WHEN(CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(bccbnc AS STRING))>5) THEN SUBSTR(name,1,6) =   
CAST(bccbnc AS STRING)

ELSE SUBSTR(name,1,5) = CAST(bccbnc AS STRING)
END)
```

I am getting error

Error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

It works if I remove CASE.

Comment: Can you modify query?

Comment: Normally the answer would be to use `cross join` with `where`. However, despite of never qualifying your columns, you are not getting a "Column name ... is ambiguous" error message. Can you explain what is the end result you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery, unlike MySQL is not very good at joining on complex relationships.

I suggest you create an intermediary/temporary (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause)) table where you can then join on a equality (even a view works for those matters)

You can create a column that uses that case statement:

```
CASE
WHEN(SUBSTR(name,1,6)='000000') THEN mtr 
WHEN(CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(bccbnc AS STRING))>5) THEN SUBSTR(name,1,6) 
ELSE SUBSTR(name,1,5) end as column_to_join_onbccbnc
```

And then on join on it

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you modify my query little bit to explain?

Comment: so, what are the columns you have on table2?

Comment: I can write you the query but I need the schema